# Plotting a datetime serie, counting the values for another serie

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am stuck on a plotting issue. I've done some research before asking for help.

I've a dataframe that looks like this:

```
date            text
2020-08-18      hey what's up?
2020-08-18      all good here
2020-08-17      happy Monday
2020-08-17      no news good news
2020-08-17      it's been a while
2020-08-16      see you tomorrow
```

Long story short, I'm trying to plot a vertical bar chart, or a line plot, with ['date'] as my x and the COUNT of ['text'] as my y. There are 2 entries for 2020-08-18, 3 entries for 2020-08-17, and 1 for 2020-08-16.

Using SQL I'd simply have to do something like:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(date) AS count_date FROM my_table GROUP BY date
```

With Python I've been over complicating things, doing this:

```
df['date_count'] = df.groupby(['date'])['date'].transform('size')
df_temporary = df.loc[ : , ['date', 'date_count'] ].drop_duplicates()
```

And I can then plot the whole thing doing either:

```
sns.plotline(data=df_temporary, x='date', y='date_count')
```

or its Matplotlib equivalent:

```
plt.line(df_temporary.date, df_temporary.date_count)
```

It works, but I mean, it can't be that complicated, right?

What's the obvious thing that I'm not seeing? How do I get the COUNT for each unique date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a temporary dataframe, to count uniuqe date per date.

```
temp['date_count'] = df.groupby(['date'])['date'].nunique().reset_index()
```

Then use it to plot your charts

```
sns.plotline(data=temp, x='date', y='date_count')
```

Comment: That's great, as I can use this in Altair too :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is:

```
ax = df.groupby('date').size().plot(kind='bar')
```

Which gives you a very plain looking chart which you can customize to your liking:

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly with Matplotlib, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. All these things can be done in one line.

```
plt.plot(df.groupby("date").apply(len))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are close indeed, the syntax is actually very similair to SQL

the key would be `df.groupby(key to group by)[target column for agg function].count()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO

d = """date            text
2020-08-18      hey what's up?
2020-08-18      all good here
2020-08-17      happy Monday
2020-08-17      no news good news
2020-08-17      it's been a while
2020-08-16      see you tomorrow"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),sep='\s\s+',parse_dates=['date'])

df.groupby('date')['date'].count().plot(kind='line',title='Count of Text by Date'
                                   )
```

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate the help on this. I was close indeed, and yet so far :)